# Write to file List element of struct

Tags: c#

I have such struct:

```
public struct ParsedUser
{
    public string Username;
    public string pk;
    public string RandPhotoId;
}
```

And I have filled List of `ParsedUser`:

```
List<ParsedUser> users;
```

How to write to file only Usernames?

Something like  `File.AppendAllLines(tag + ".txt", users.Select(x => new { x.Username} ));`

Answer (score 2):

You were close:

```
File.AppendAllLines(tag + ".txt", string.Join("\r\n", users.Select(u => u.Username)));
```

First of all you don't need to create a new object, you want just the name, so select it plainly.

Second, ju need to join these strings with "\r\n", a newline plus carriage return, that is what the string.Join does.

Comment: It's better to use Environment.NewLine here.

Comment: `string.Join` is kinda unnecessary since you are using `AppendAllLines`, it would just be fine if you just select usernames. edit: or actually it's not just unnecessary it's invalid as well cause AppendAllLines expects an `IEnumerable<string>` as second argument

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use :

```
 var userNames = users.Select(x => x.Username).ToArray();
 File.AppendAllLines(tag + ".txt", userNames);
```

Method `AppendAllLines` create new line per every string in `IEnumerable<string>`.